# OpenKinect wrapper in Java

Tags: java, junit4, jna, hamcrest, openkinect

I'm trying to use OpenKinect's wrapper in Java from this address:
https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/tree/master/wrappers/java
I've also added the jna-3.0.9.jar, hamcrest-all-1.3.jar, and junit-4.8.jar to the project, so now everything is perfect, except there is a line in Freenect.java which has an error: Native.register(instance);

The method 'register' does not even exist for 'Native' !! Does anybody familiar with openkinect know what's wrong with this?

Comment: [Native.register(String)](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#register(java.lang.String)).  Perhaps you're not using the proper version of JNA?

Comment: @technomage  Yes...exactly! I changed it and at least I don't get any errors and I can run the program...But now there is another problem: Unable to load library 'freenect': Native library (win32-x86-64/freenect.dll) not found in resource path ...how can I find the exact freenect library? I could not find it in the project resources, and they don't get compiled for me!

Comment: You're using a 64-bit JVM, so you need to ensure that the 64-bit version of `freenect.dll` is either in `%PATH%` or `jna.library.path`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe if the version is not 64bit, the library is not added properly. Check it with more details...